# Writing to Output Stream from Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For some strange reasons, I want to write HTML directly to the Response stream from a controller action.
(I understand MVC separation, but this is a special case.)

Can I write directly into the `HttpResponse` stream? In that case, which `IView` object should the controller action should return? Can I return 'null'?

Answer (score 50):

I used a class derived from `FileResult` to achieve this using normal MVC pattern:

```
/// <summary>
/// MVC action result that generates the file content using a delegate that writes the content directly to the output stream.
/// </summary>
public class FileGeneratingResult : FileResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The delegate that will generate the file content.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Action<System.IO.Stream> content;

    private readonly bool bufferOutput;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FileGeneratingResult" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
    /// <param name="contentType">Type of the content.</param>
    /// <param name="content">Delegate with Stream parameter. This is the stream to which content should be written.</param>
    /// <param name="bufferOutput">use output buffering. Set to false for large files to prevent OutOfMemoryException.</param>
    public FileGeneratingResult(string fileName, string contentType, Action<System.IO.Stream> content,bool bufferOutput=true)
        : base(contentType)
    {
        if (content == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("content");

        this.content = content;
        this.bufferOutput = bufferOutput;
        FileDownloadName = fileName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the file to the response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The response object.</param>
    protected override void WriteFile(System.Web.HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.Buffer = bufferOutput;
        content(response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

The controller method would now be like this:

```
public ActionResult Export(int id)
{
    return new FileGeneratingResult(id + ".csv", "text/csv",
        stream => this.GenerateExportFile(id, stream));
}

public void GenerateExportFile(int id, Stream stream)
{
    stream.Write(/**/);
}
```

Note that if buffering is turned off,

```
stream.Write(/**/);
```

becomes extremely slow.  The solution is to use a BufferedStream.  Doing so improved performance by approximately 100x in one case.  See

[Unbuffered Output Very Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26010915/141172)

Comment: Best answer - just add the file once, and reuse this concept in every other situation using the flexible delegate parameter.

Comment: Note if you write a large file in this manner, you may get an `OutOfMemoryException`.  You can resolve by turning off buffering.  Add a line to `WriteFile()` like this: `response.Buffer = false;`

Comment: Nice solution. +1 Took liberty of rolling @EricJ. 's suggestion into this answer (and updating xmldocs). Feel free to roll back if this offends.

Comment: @spender: I discovered a caveat... turning off buffering makes the output *extremely* slow.  Adding in a BufferedStream resolves that.  I updated the answer with that information.

Comment: Does this work if the writing is done asynchronously and the WriteFile method returns before the request is complete? I can't find anything by googling for "FileResult" and "async".

Comment: is this solution able to use in aspnet core?

Comment: @liang see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178983/how-to-create-a-response-message-and-add-content-string-to-it-in-asp-net-5-mvc

Comment: Im trying to use your solution with Xml but the result is an empty xml file return new FileGeneratingResult(fileName, "text/xml", stream => xmlDocument.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))); am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can write directly to the Response.  After you're done, you can call CompleteRequest() and you shouldn't need to return anything.

For example:

```
// GET: /Test/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

    Response.Write("hi");
    HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

    return View();     // does not execute!
}
```

Comment: You should avoid Response.End() http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/use-httpapplication-completerequest-instead-of-response-end/

Comment: Updated then to use CompleteRequest().

Comment: May be useful to replace "return View()" by "return Content("")" to avoid errors about missing view. But is this approach safely?

Comment: this is not a good approach because no ActionFilter attributes will be executed after the completion of this method.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to derive your own result type, you can simply write to `Response.OutputStream` and return `new EmptyResult()`.

Answer (score 5):

Write your own Action Result. Here's an example of one of mine:

```
public class RssResult : ActionResult
{
    public RssFeed RssFeed { get; set; }

    public RssResult(RssFeed feed) {
        RssFeed = feed;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
        SyndicationResourceSaveSettings settings = new SyndicationResourceSaveSettings();
        settings.CharacterEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        RssFeed.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `return Content(...);` where, if I remember correctly, `...` would be what you want to write directly to the output stream, or nothing at all.

Take a look at the `Content` methods on the `Controller`: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22907#266451

And the `ContentResult`: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22907#266450