# ASP.NET MVC: How can I get the browser to open and display a PDF instead of displaying a download prompt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

Ok, so I have an action method that generates a PDF and returns it to the browser. The problem is that instead of automatically opening the PDF, IE displays a download prompt even though it knows what kind of file it is. Chrome does the same thing. In both browsers if I click a link to a PDF file that is stored on a server it will open up just fine and never display a download prompt.

Here is the code that is called to return the PDF:

```
public FileResult Report(int id)
{
    var customer = customersRepository.GetCustomer(id);
    if (customer != null)
    {
        return File(RenderPDF(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/Forms/Report.aspx", customer), "application/pdf", "Report - Customer # " + id.ToString() + ".pdf");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's the response header from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 16 Sep 2010 06:14:13 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Report - Customer # 60.pdf"
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 79244
Connection: Close
```

Do I have to add something special to the response to get the browser to open the PDF automatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Looks as a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3206682/1178314), but asked way better.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=foo.pdf");
return File(...
```

Comment: This returns duplicate Content-Disposition headers, and Chrome rejects the file.  Is there a way to the use the File method but return the file inline without duplicate headers?

Comment: @wilk, don't keep the filename inside of the call to File(...)

Comment: Thought I'd add - to force a download switch "inline;" to be "attachment;".

Answer (score 18):

On the HTTP level your 'Content-Disposition' header should have 'inline' not 'attachment'.
Unfortunately, that's not supported by the FileResult (or it's derived classes) directly.

If you're already generating the document in a page or handler you could simply redirect the browser there. If that's not what you want you could subclass the FileResult and add support for streaming documents inline.

```
public class CustomFileResult : FileContentResult
   {
      public CustomFileResult( byte[] fileContents, string contentType ) : base( fileContents, contentType )
      {
      }

      public bool Inline { get; set; }

      public override void ExecuteResult( ControllerContext context )
      {
         if( context == null )
         {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "context" );
         }
         HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
         response.ContentType = ContentType;
         if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( FileDownloadName ) )
         {
            string str = new ContentDisposition { FileName = this.FileDownloadName, Inline = Inline }.ToString();
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", str );
         }
         WriteFile( response );
      }
   }
```

A simpler solution is not to specify the filename on the `Controller.File` method. This way you will not get the ContentDisposition header, which means you loose the file name hint when saving the PDF.

Comment: I have gone the ContentDisposition helper class way first, just to realize MVC was using it internally too, but with some hack for correctly handling utf-8 file name. ContentDisposition helper class does it wrong when it has to encode utf-8 values. For more details, see [my comment here](/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header/22221217#comment57484455_22221217).

Comment: Your comment about 'not specify the filename' was great!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue,but none of the solutions not worked in **Firefox** until I changed the Options of my browser. In `Options`

window,then  `Application Tab` change the `Portable Document Format` to `Preview in Firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

I use following classes for having more options with content-disposition header.

It works quite like [Marnix answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724495/1178314), but instead of fully generating the header with the `ContentDisposition` class, which unfortunately does not comply to [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3) when file name has to be utf-8 encoded, it tweaks instead the header generated by MVC, which complies to RFC.

(Originally, I have written that in part using [this response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13456219/1178314) and this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26010915/1178314).)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Whatever
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add to FilePathResult some properties for specifying file name without forcing a download and specifying size.
    /// And add a workaround for allowing error cases to still display error page.
    /// </summary>
    public class FilePathResultEx : FilePathResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// In case a file name has been supplied, control whether it should be opened inline or downloaded.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public bool Inline { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether file size should be indicated or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public bool IncludeSize { get; set; }

        public FilePathResultEx(string fileName, string contentType) : base(fileName, contentType) { }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            FileResultUtils.ExecuteResultWithHeadersRestoredOnFailure(context, base.ExecuteResult);
        }

        protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            if (Inline)
                FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionAsInline(response);
            // File.Exists is more robust than testing through FileInfo, especially in case of invalid path: it does yield false rather than an exception.
            // We wish not to crash here, in order to let FilePathResult crash in its usual way.
            if (IncludeSize && File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);
                FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionSize(response, fileInfo.Length);
            }
            base.WriteFile(response);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add to FileStreamResult some properties for specifying file name without forcing a download and specifying size.
    /// And add a workaround for allowing error cases to still display error page.
    /// </summary>
    public class FileStreamResultEx : FileStreamResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// In case a file name has been supplied, control whether it should be opened inline or downloaded.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public bool Inline { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If greater than <c>0</c>, the content size to include in content-disposition header.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public long Size { get; set; }

        public FileStreamResultEx(Stream fileStream, string contentType) : base(fileStream, contentType) { }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            FileResultUtils.ExecuteResultWithHeadersRestoredOnFailure(context, base.ExecuteResult);
        }

        protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            if (Inline)
                FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionAsInline(response);
            FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionSize(response, Size);
            base.WriteFile(response);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add to FileContentResult some properties for specifying file name without forcing a download and specifying size.
    /// And add a workaround for allowing error cases to still display error page.
    /// </summary>
    public class FileContentResultEx : FileContentResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// In case a file name has been supplied, control whether it should be opened inline or downloaded.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public bool Inline { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether file size should be indicated or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>If <c>FileDownloadName</c> is <c>null</c> or empty, this property has no effect (due to current implementation).</remarks>
        public bool IncludeSize { get; set; }

        public FileContentResultEx(byte[] fileContents, string contentType) : base(fileContents, contentType) { }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            FileResultUtils.ExecuteResultWithHeadersRestoredOnFailure(context, base.ExecuteResult);
        }

        protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            if (Inline)
                FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionAsInline(response);
            if (IncludeSize)
                FileResultUtils.TweakDispositionSize(response, FileContents.LongLength);
            base.WriteFile(response);
        }
    }

    public static class FileResultUtils
    {
        public static void ExecuteResultWithHeadersRestoredOnFailure(ControllerContext context, Action<ControllerContext> executeResult)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            if (executeResult == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("executeResult");
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            var previousContentType = response.ContentType;
            try
            {
                executeResult(context);
            }
            catch
            {
                if (response.HeadersWritten)
                    throw;
                // Error logic will usually output a content corresponding to original content type. Restore it if response can still be rewritten.
                // (Error logic should ensure headers positionning itself indeed... But this is not the case at least with HandleErrorAttribute.)
                response.ContentType = previousContentType;
                // If a content-disposition header have been set (through DownloadFilename), it must be removed too.
                response.Headers.Remove(ContentDispositionHeader);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private const string ContentDispositionHeader = "Content-Disposition";

        // Unfortunately, the content disposition generation logic is hidden in an Mvc.Net internal class, while not trivial (UTF-8 support).
        // Hacking it after its generation. 
        // Beware, do not try using System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition instead, it does not conform to the RFC. It does some base64 UTF-8
        // encoding while it should append '*' to parameter name and use RFC 5987 encoding. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3
        // And https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221217/1178314 comment.
        // To ask for a fix: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc
        // Other class : System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue looks better. But requires to detect if the filename needs encoding
        // and if yes, use the 'Star' suffixed property along with setting the sanitized name in non Star property.
        // MVC 6 relies on ASP.NET 5 https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions which provide a forked version of previous class, with a method
        // for handling that: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/ContentDispositionHeaderValue.cs
        // MVC 6 stil does not give control on FileResult content-disposition header.
        public static void TweakDispositionAsInline(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            var disposition = response.Headers[ContentDispositionHeader];
            const string downloadModeToken = "attachment;";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(disposition) || !disposition.StartsWith(downloadModeToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return;

            response.Headers.Remove(ContentDispositionHeader);
            response.Headers.Add(ContentDispositionHeader, "inline;" + disposition.Substring(downloadModeToken.Length));
        }

        public static void TweakDispositionSize(HttpResponseBase response, long size)
        {
            if (size <= 0)
                return;
            var disposition = response.Headers[ContentDispositionHeader];
            const string sizeToken = "size=";
            // Due to current ancestor semantics (no file => inline, file name => download), handling lack of ancestor content-disposition
            // is non trivial. In this case, the content is by default inline, while the Inline property is <c>false</c> by default.
            // This could lead to an unexpected behavior change. So currently not handled.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(disposition) || disposition.Contains(sizeToken))
                return;

            response.Headers.Remove(ContentDispositionHeader);
            response.Headers.Add(ContentDispositionHeader, disposition + "; " + sizeToken + size.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```c#
public FileResult Download(int id)
{
    // some code to get filepath and filename for browser
    ...

    return
        new FilePathResultEx(filepath, System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename))
        {
            FileDownloadName = filename,
            Inline = true
        };
}
```

Note that specifying a file name with `Inline` will not work with Internet Explorer (11 included, Windows 10 Edge included, tested with some pdf files), while it works with Firefox and Chrome. Internet Explorer will ignore the file name. For Internet Explorer, you need to hack your url path, which is quite bad imo. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252657/1178314).

Answer (score 0):

Just return a `FileStreamResult` instead of `File`

And make sure you don't wrap your new FileStreamResult in a File at the end.  Just return the FileStreamResult as it is.  And probably you need to modify the return type of the action also to FileSteamResult