# How to open PDF file in a new tab or window instead of downloading it using C# and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have invoice screen and in this screen there are number of order are available so when we create invoice there are one form we need to fill so I want solution is when I submit this invoice form or click this submit button pdf should be open in new tab. I want to clarify to you we are not save this pdf anywhere.

```
<div class="modal-footer custom-no-top-border">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createdata" value="@T("Admin.Common.Create")" />
</div>
```

When I click on this button, the pdf should be opened in a new tab.

Here is pdf code

```
 [HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult PdfInvoice(int customerOrderselectedId)
 {
        var customerOrder = _customerOrderService.GetCustomerOrderById(customerOrderselectedId);

        var customerOrders = new List<DD_CustomerOrder>();

        customerOrders.Add(customerOrder);
        byte[] bytes;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            _customerOrderPdfService.PrintInvoicePdf(stream, customerOrders);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return File(bytes, MimeTypes.ApplicationPdf, string.Format("order_{0}.pdf", customerOrder.Id));
    }
```

This code downloads the pdf when I click on the button.

Thank you !!

Comment: Use `a` with `target=blank` and mark your `ActionMethod` as `HttpGet`.

Comment: also, ensure to set this HTTP headers: `Content-Type: application/pdf` and `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most important thing is `Controller.File()` works with `[HttpGet]`, hence you should do these steps:

1) Change HTTP method type from `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` and set `return File()` without specifying `fileDownloadName` parameter (using overload of [`Controller.File()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_File_System_Byte___System_String_) which accepts 2 parameters).

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult PdfInvoice(int customerOrderselectedId)
{
    var customerOrder = _customerOrderService.GetCustomerOrderById(customerOrderselectedId);

    var customerOrders = new List<DD_CustomerOrder>();

    customerOrders.Add(customerOrder);
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _customerOrderPdfService.PrintInvoicePdf(stream, customerOrders);
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    // use 2 parameters
    return File(bytes, MimeTypes.ApplicationPdf);
}
```

2) Handle `click` event of that button (preferred using `<input type="button" .../>`) and use `_blank` option, or use an anchor tag (`<a>`) with `target='_blank'` attribute:

```
$('#createdata').click(function (e) {
    // if using type="submit", this is mandatory
    e.preventDefault();

    window.open('@Url.Action("PdfInvoice", "ControllerName", new { customerOrderselectedId = selectedId })', '_blank');
});
```

The reason why `fileDownloadName` parameter is not used here is that parameter sets `Content-Disposition: attachment` while file name is provided, otherwise if you're omit it or using `null` value, then `Content-Disposition: inline` will be set automatically.

Note that because you're using `FileResult`, you should not setting `Content-Disposition` using `Response.AddHeader` before `return File()` like this, because doing so will sent multiple `Content-Disposition` headers which causing browser to not display the file:

```
// this is wrong way, should not be used
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=order_XXX.pdf");
return File(bytes, MimeTypes.ApplicationPdf);
```

Related issues:

[How To Open PDF File In New Tab In MVC Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-new-tab-in-mvc-using-c-sharp)

[ASP.NET MVC: How can I get the browser to open and display a PDF instead of displaying a download prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724278/asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-get-the-browser-to-open-and-display-a-pdf-instead-of-disp)

[Stream file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult in a browser with a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name/3252657)

Comment: your answer help me in another problem, I want to do label to open the pdf in another tab and I do : <label id="Show"  onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("ViewDocument", "Devices", new { id = item.Id  })', '_blank')">Show</label>