# Stream out large datatable to excel file

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, stream

I am trying stream out a datatable to an excel file in MVC. It gives me OutOfMemory exception for large when number of rows exceeds 250,000. Following is the code :

```
   var memStream = new MemoryStream();
   var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memStream);

   streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "<TABLE>");
   foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
   {
       streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "<TR>");
       foreach (DataColumn cl in dt.Columns)
       {
             streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "<TD>");
             streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", rw[cl].ToString());
             streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "</TD>");
       }
       streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "</TR>");

    }
    streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", "</TABLE>");

    streamWriter.Flush();
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(memStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Test.xls");
```

I think that writing to memory stream through buffer should solve the OutOfMemory problem. However, I have not been able to do so. How should I modify the above code for buffered write to the memory stream ?

Thanks

Comment: Would it help if you called `streamWriter.Flush()` inside your loop? Generally, flush takes everything in the buffer and writes it, so I would think that would help. On second thought, though, if you are trying to put something into your MemoryStream that exceeds your available memory, that might not help.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK : Tried `streamwriter.Flush()`. It doesn't help.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK : Thanks! It helped me figure out writing to `FileStream` will solve OutOfMemory problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run out of memory because the whole table is written to memory first regardless if the StreamWriter is flushed or not before it is sent to the client.

Solutions:

1. Write to context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream directly instead of memory. Con:
   messy and you have to take care of the headers like Content-Type and Content-Disposition.
2. My prefered solution. See the top answer to this question: [Writing to Output Stream from Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943122/writing-to-output-stream-from-action)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that the complete table is too big for the memory. So used `FileStream` instead.