# Stream Generated File to Browser without Writing to File System

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that I can return a file from a controller action using code like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return File(PathToTheFile);
}
```

There is also an overload that accepts a Stream rather than a file path.

In my case, I dynamically create a CSV file based on a database query.  It would be simpler to write that CSV file directly to the response, and have the response treated as a file.  Is it possible to do that?  How?

**EDIT**

I assume that I would be writing to some sort of stream, but what kind of stream and who is responsible for disposing it?

Comment: So the user never needs to download the CSV file? Why create a CSV file (or any file) at all? Just query the database and display that data to the user on a page (formatted the way you want)

Comment: @rwisch45: The file should be downloaded, I just do not want to temporarily write it to the file system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to Output Stream from Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943122/writing-to-output-stream-from-action)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

As you create output dynamically and would like to avoid creating file and memory stream to improve performance and avoid additional I/O, a simple solution is to directly write to Http Response.  The following code is a example that works for me. You may use the same method for your data.

```
public ActionResult getFile()
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myVFile.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";


        //sample data 
        string[] data = { "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3" };


        //Query data with LINQ  - This can be done in diffrent ways 
        (from item in data
         where
            //Some conditions
            item != "-4"
         select
         //Select whatever you want to be in the output 
         item
         )
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(
              //Write items from your LINQ Query to HTTP Response 
               item => Response.Write(item + ",")
        );

        //You can use a foreach loop instead of chaining ForEach in LINQ as above 


        Response.End();

        return Content(null);
    }
```

Comment: How would CreateMyFile write to a stream?  What kind of stream?  How is the stream disposed?

Comment: If I was going to stream a file to Response, I would use MemoryString as below : 
            private static Stream CreateMyFile()
            {
            string filename = "myfile.csv";
            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return ms;
        }  You may replace the line `byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`  to create content from your database or any other way you wish ....

Comment: But that requires a) actually having a file on disk (trying to avoid that), and b) reading all of the bytes into memory before streaming them out.

Comment: how do you create your final content that you would like to stream to response as downloadable file? Is it by an iteration through a collection or a LINQ query? Can you paste your content creation method here so that can help to suggest a better solution.

Comment: I iterate a Linq query.  I *could* write the results of the link query to a file stream and then return that file as the ActionResult.  However, I'm trying to avoid writing that file.