# ASP.NET Core API Controller: Response.Body.WriteAsync base64 string not working

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core, base64, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to return a base64 string representing a jpeg image from an API Controller and set it as the src of an `<img>` but all my attempts failed.

Here is the very simple HTML:

```
<img src="/api/TestBase64Image" alt="image test" />
```

And my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestBase64ImageController : Controller
{
    private const string _base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7Sfg.....";
    private const string _base64Image2 = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7Sfg.....";

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        //Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg").ToString();
        //Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain").ToString();

        //Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", _base64Image.Length.ToString());
        //HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = _base64Image.Length;

        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_base64Image), 0, _base64Image.Length);
        //await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

I've tried several things, like removing `FlushAsync()`, changing the way to define the `ContentType`, include `data:image/jpeg;base64`, in the string or not but nothing is working.

I've seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/822) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186680/1203116) that writing in the Response body stream is doable, so I presume I'm on the good way (I've tried to return a simple string before but not working as well).

Yes my base64 string is correct because I've also tried to include it directly into the HTML and the image shows up correctly.

I precise I don't want to use any JavaScript or Razor view to achieve that, only pure HTML and my controller.

Also please pay attention that I'm inside an API Controller. I can't do the same as we see in the `Configure` method in the `Startup` class of an empty ASP.NET Core project like:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```

Even though both Responses' types are `HttpResponse`, the one in my controller doesn't have any `Response.WriteAsync` but `Response.Body.WriteAsync`

Thanks for your help, it's been hours I'm searching but there is almost no resources about this yet for ASP.NET Core

Comment: Why are you trying to return a base64 image when it's requested? The point of base64 data URIs is to embed the data within the HTML. For just a regular image fetch, you should return the binary data directly.

Comment: I'm in a context of having the image as a base64 string, I don't have any physical file to serve. But isn't it what I'm doing, returning binary data using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`? I'm lost the way to do this because in old ASP.NET (non-MVC) I did that using `Response.BinaryWrite` but there is no such thing in Core...

Comment: For the record, the reason your controller code does not have "Response.WriteAsync()" is because you did NOT include the namespace with the required extension method. ;)  Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` to your controller page and it will be there. TIP: If you type the extension method name, VS will try to resolve it for you with the quick action prompt.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the solution worked!
Just add the package from "Manage NuGet packages" and then install: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions "version = 1.1.2" (in my case). Finally in the source code, I added: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; Thanks for help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're still returning the data as base64 text, basically - you're getting the UTF-8 encoded form of it, but that's all.

If you really only have the base64 version of the image, you just need to decode that:

```
byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(_base64Image2);
await Response.Body.WriteAsync(image, 0, image.Length);
```

(Note that it needs to be just the base64 you convert - not the data URI.)

Comment: Wow the solution was so simple, I'm wondering how I missed that... Super fast answer, thanks a lot Jon. (`WriteAsync` is also waiting the `offset` and the `length`, I let you edit your answer...)