# return base64 encoded images directly from a web api core endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have seen these SO answers:

- [Return an image from asp.net web api core as IActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038912/return-an-image-from-asp-net-web-api-core-as-iactionresult)
- [Response.Body.WriteAsync base64 string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994695/asp-net-core-api-controller-response-body-writeasync-base64-string-not-working)

but these either serve physical files directly or serve from a byte array.

Please is there a way for our Web API Endpoint to return content-type: image/png directly from data:image/png;base64,(our base64 string)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is quite straight forward to read a file from a folder. The trick is to use ***IHostingEnvironment*** in ***ASP.NET Core*** to get the current web root path.

### FilesController

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DemoWebApiCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public FilesController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        // GET api/files/sample.png
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        public string Get(string fileName)
        {
            string path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/images/" + fileName;
            byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
namespace DemoWebApiCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```html
<html>
<body>
    <img id="sample-img" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var url = "/api/files/sample.png";
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#sample-img").attr('src', data);
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so in effect, i can read byte[] b = GetFromDatabase() and return the base64 directly as "data:image/png;base64," ++ base64 to the src attribute of an image. nice

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return images as base64 string you can do it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetImage()
{
    var image = GetImageData();
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image);

    return Ok(base64);
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. What is result?

Comment: @juunas my bad, fixed the code, you need to read the image data and simply pass it to Convert.ToBase64String

Comment: I don't follow. How does this help? We need to return an image/png. you are just returning a string

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu You said "base64 image String" if this is not what you need, I think your question needs some clarification

Comment: @ShahriarGholami I've corrected the question. What i'm looking for is a way to serve content-type: image/png directly from data:image/png;base64,xxxx. I'm not just returning a string. thanks