# Response is null for Http Post call to web api - Angular 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, rxjs

I am trying to make a post call to web api from Angular 4 using HttpClient.

**Here's my service where post call is made:**

```
public add<T>(type:string, item: T): Observable<any> {
        console.log("api data : " + this.url + type);
        return this.http
            .post(this.url + type, JSON.stringify(item)).map((res: Response) => { console.log("rese: "+res); res});
    }
```

**Here is the code which subscribe to above written service:**

```
addArticleType(articleType: ArticleType): void {
        console.log("Service data : " + articleType);
        this.service.add("ArticleType", articleType).subscribe((val: any) => this.response = val),
            (error: any) => { console.log("Error is: " + error) },
            () => { console.log("resp: " + this.response) };

    }
```

**And here's the API**

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Add(A item)
    {
        int a = this.service.Add(item);
        log.Debug("value: " + a);
        if (a > 0)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent("Data saved successfully.", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }

        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "Failed to save data");

    }
```

On Post call, API receives the call and do its task to store data in database. But whatever response is sent by API as HttpResponseMessage is not received by Angular.

As you see in service, I am trying to print response in console. This always prints null. In response I expect the message which is sent by API "Data saved successfully.", but instead I get null value.

I might be missing something very basic. I have looked over many articles and blogs but didn't find anything which could solve the issue.

**Update:**

As per provided guide, I updated my code as below.

**Post Call**

```
  public add<T>(type:string, item: T): Observable<T> {
    console.log("api data : " + this.url + type);
    return this.http
        .post<T>(this.url + type, item);
}
```

**Subscription**

```
addArticleType(articleType: ArticleType): void {
        console.log("Service data : " + articleType);
        this.service.add<ArticleType>("ArticleType", articleType)
            .subscribe(
            (val: any) => {
                this.response = val;
                console.log("res sub: " + this.response);
            },
            (error: any) => { console.log("Error is: " + error) },
            () => { console.log("resp: " + this.response) });

    }
```

It still prints response as null  in console.

Comment: 1st) why do you stringify the body? 2nd) you never map the response

Comment: Why do you think that the response type of the `HttpClient.post` method is `Response`? Please read the http guide in angular.io

Comment: And the map inside of the add method should have a return.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo we dont know he uses the httpclient instead of http. and the map doesnt need a return but instead probably needs to become `.map(res => res.json())`

Comment: doing this: ".map(res => res.json())" throws error as "Cant read json of null".

Comment: Can you see the arriving response in the Network tab of the dev console?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Even with response of any type doesn't help with the problem.

Comment: in which case, the server doesnt return json, what type of data does the server return to you?

Comment: It returns null. Thats the issue

Comment: To Downvoters: Downvoting a genuine question without any helpful comment doesn't help the community my friends.

Comment: OP mentioned he is using the `HttpClient` API. Please add the declaration of the http member in your service. Refer to https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data for further guidance

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have updated my code as per the guide.. It still returns response as null. Please see updated question.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please read question carefully and try to understand the problem first before making any judgement. This is a kind request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server return nothing (status 200 without body), you need to set `responseType: 'text'` for handle that behavior

```
...
public add<T>(type:string, item: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.url + type, item, { responseType: 'text' });
}
...
```

And in controller simply handle success and error call

```
this.service.add("ArticleType", articleType).subscribe(
  () => // success handle,
  err => // error handle
)
```

If you need to receive a text message in response body, you need to make sure that it delivered in dev console (if network response is empty, check this [How to create a response message and add content string to it in ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178983/how-to-create-a-response-message-and-add-content-string-to-it-in-asp-net-5-mvc))
When response received in browser, you can handle it like:

```
...
// Service
public add<T>(type:string, item: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.url + type, item);
}

...
// Controller
this.service.add("ArticleType", articleType).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
    // here some success handle,
  }
  err => // error handle
)
```

Comment: Try to `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Your message here");` in your server `Add()` method

Comment: You were right. The issue was with the type of response. Adding { responseType: 'text' } to the post did the job. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are returning valid JSON in this server-side code:

```
  response.Content = new StringContent(
       "Data saved successfully.",
       Encoding.UTF8,
       "application/json");
```

you should have something that looks like:

```
  response.Content = new StringContent(
       "{\"Result\": \"Data saved successfully.\"}",
       Encoding.UTF8,
       "application/json");
```

Comment: A string is a valid JSON token. Whether or not the client API can handle that I don't know, and if they document that they expect a JSON *object* than that may be the issue, but if they're meant to accept any JSON token then that is a valid server response.

Comment: Strings are valid JSON tokens when enclosed in quote characters. What I didn't detail in my answer is that the code in the question attempts to return an *application/json* media type response. This media type requires the response be either a valid JSON object or and array of JSON objects. This is evident in the accepted answer, the client code was change to "force" the acceptance of a *text* response to properly handle the string.

Comment: Good point. I figured `StringContent` would actually be a string, but it seems like it isn't, and the `application/json` seems to agree. However, I do not see how the media type requires it to be an object or array. Do you have a link for that? RFC 8259 seems to indicate that all JSON tokens are valid "JSON texts", as it calls them. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also didn't see that the RFC specifically states the response must only contain the two 'structural' types it describes. The second paragraph in original specification of JSON [found at this site](https://json.org/) does make it clear only those two types make valid JSON. Most HTTP clients that I've used seem to make the same assumption. It certain was the root cause of the problem the question described.

Thanks for looking up the RFC! This taught me to avoid assuming they necessarily contain what I see in the specs they're based on.