# Make RESTful Endpoint that uses Streams

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core (RC2) WebApi project, and for one of the APIs, I need to take in a zip file, ideally as a Stream, and then return another zip file, again ideally as a stream.  Is this possible?

Right now my web api gets and returns a base 64 encoded string... I feel using Streams would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to access the HTTP stream from within a Controller. You could probably adapt it. [Writing to Output Stream from Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943122/writing-to-output-stream-from-action)